# TextField() - how to prevent mouse select

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

How can I prevent mouse selecting (and moving caret) with Editable TextField(),
this one does not seem to fully work when SELECTING text, but it prevents clicking. I want to keep cursor in place where its going.

```
protected function handleMouseDEvent(evt:MouseEvent):void {
if (evt.type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN) {
var max : int;
max = this.text.length;
this.setSelection(max, max) // SET CURSOR POSITION  
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry to just follow a question with a question, but why would you want this behaviour?

Comment: Yeah, if you tell us what your end goal is we might have better suggestions. This will be a bit of a hack regardless how you go about it, so there might be better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about selectable="false"?

Answer (score 3):

if what you mean is to prevent the TextField for being selected, use:

```
TextField.selectable = false;
```

But if what you mean is to prevent the TextField from blocking object behind it, use:

```
TextField.mouseEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried programmatically switching the textfield from input to dynamic?

Comment: How can it be editable but always have the cursor at the end of the text field?

Answer (score 0):

whenever the user has focus the textfield, put a transparent button on top of the text field , set the button to not using handCursor

and once the user is not focusing the text field, remove the transparent button